# RSA : recovering a few missing bytes in an almost complete plaintext

Tags: rsa

I have a RSA-4096 public key, a ciphertext, and almost the whole plaintext : there are only a couple dozens bytes missing near the end, or in other terms, I know the range 0-80% + 90-100% of the plaintext. Is there any way to recover those missing bytes ?

Comment: Is this textbook RSA, or did the encryptor use real (randomized) RSA encryption padding?  If the latter, well, you're a bit out of luck...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify about padding. There is none actually, the plaintext is only ~320 bytes long out of 512.

Answer (score 3):

If the encryption exponent is less than one over the proportion of missing plaintext, then you can use [Coppersmith's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith_method).

For example, if you are missing bits 3300-3699 of the plaintext, let $t$ be the known plaintext with zeros in places 3300-3699 of the unknown. Then the plaintext is $t+2^{3300}x$ for some unknown number less than $2^{400}$ and the ciphertext is $c(x)=(t+2^{3300}x)^e\pmod N$ where $e$ is the encryption exponent. This can be solved if $x<N^{1/e}$.

Comment: The encryption exponent indeed meets your criteria. I'll go check this method, then. Thank you !

Comment: I think this is a CTF/HW. Anyway,  It should be rather $(t+2^{300}x) < N^{1/e}$

Comment: It is soluble if $|x|<N^{1/e}$, but if this is a CTF it’s probably best to leave that as one of many details to be worked out.